# How to change object color with keyboard in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to change my triangle color but it doesn't happen.When i press 'k' is has to be random color.Is there any way to do this task basically or different ways.Here is my code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec4 vPosition;

    void main() {
       gl_Position = vPosition;
    }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    uniform vec4 u_color;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = u_color;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="b.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="640" height="360" style="border: solid;"></canvas>
</body>
```

And my script code;

```
    var gl;

var color = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1];

window.onload = function init() {

    var triangle = new Float32Array(
        [ 0.2 , -0.4,
          0.8,  -0.4,
          0.5,   0.5 ]);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn’t available"); }


    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader"); 
    gl.useProgram(program);

    var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);

    var vbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle, gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition"); 
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); 
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed); }
    function checkKeyPressed(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == "84") {
        color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
        alert("t pressed");
    }
   }
```

When i press <kbd>t</kbd> it shows me alert but doesn't change the triangle's color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triangle is rendered only once. You have to redraw the triangle when the key was pressed.

Create a function which sets the value of the color uniform variable and renders the triangle:

```
function render(time_ms) {

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

    var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

Use `requestAnimationFrame` to trigger the `render` function. See also [WebGLFundamentals - Animation](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-animation.html):

```
function checkKeyPressed(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == "84") {
        color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
        alert("t pressed");
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
    }
}
```

Note, alternatively you can continuously redraw the triangle, too:

```
function render(time_ms) {

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

    var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}
```

I applied the changes to your original code, see the example:

```js
var gl, program;

var color = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1];

window.onload = function init() {

    var triangle = new Float32Array(
        [ 0.2 , -0.4,
          0.8,  -0.4,
          0.5,   0.5 ]);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn’t available"); }


    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader"); 
    gl.useProgram(program);

    var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);

    var vbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle, gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition"); 
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); 
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed); 
    
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}

function render(time_ms) {
    
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

    var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}


function checkKeyPressed(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == "84") {
        color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
    }
}

function initShaders(gl, vertexShaderId, fragmentShaderId) {
  var vertShdr;
  var fragShdr;

  var vertElem = document.getElementById(vertexShaderId);
  if (!vertElem) {
    alert("Unable to load vertex shader " + vertexShaderId);
    return -1;
  } else {
    vertShdr = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertShdr, vertElem.text);
    gl.compileShader(vertShdr);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertShdr, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      var msg = "Vertex shader failed to compile.  The error log is:" + "<pre>" + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertShdr) + "</pre>";
      alert(msg);
      console.log(msg);
      return -1;
    }
  }

  var fragElem = document.getElementById(fragmentShaderId);
  if (!fragElem) {
    alert("Unable to load vertex shader " + fragmentShaderId);
    return -1;
  } else {
    fragShdr = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragShdr, fragElem.text);
    gl.compileShader(fragShdr);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragShdr, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      var msg = "Fragment shader failed to compile.  The error log is:" + "<pre>" + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragShdr) + "</pre>";
      alert(msg);
      console.log(msg);
      return -1;
    }
  }

  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertShdr);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragShdr);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    var msg = "Shader program failed to link.  The error log is:" + "<pre>" + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program) + "</pre>";
    alert(msg);
    console.log(msg);
    return -1;
  }

  return program;
}
```

```html
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec4 vPosition;

    void main() {
       gl_Position = vPosition;
    }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    uniform vec4 u_color;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = u_color;
    }
</script>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="640" height="360" style="border: solid;"></canvas>
```